# Simple MySQL Select Query Issue in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my Laravel Query for dropdown

Where i get the `$CountryID` and select the region name from the region table displaying it in the select box

But i don't know how to use `where` condition here

What is the mistake  i am doing ?

```
$CountryID = Input::get('CountryID');
$roles = DB::table('region')->lists('regionname');
foreach ($roles as $value) 
{
echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}
```

### Query : In Simple Words

How to change this query

```
$roles= DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT regionname FROM region WHERE CountryID = '$CountryID'") );
```

To Native Query :

```
$roles = DB::table('region')->lists('regionname');
```

Note : 
Now i am getting all the fields in the region  table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your query to something like:

```
$results = DB::table('region')->select('regionname', 'regionid')
->where('countryId', $CountryID)
->get();
```

This will return you an array of stdClass objects that you can access properties from:

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
    echo $result->regionid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add a where clause.

```
$CountryID = Input::get('CountryID');
$roles = DB::table('region')->where('countryId', $CountryID)->lists('regionname');
foreach ($roles as $value) 
{
echo "<option value=".$value.">".$value."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: It says "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Your Query is equivalent to select regionname from region where countryid = $countryid right ?

Comment: If i need ->lists('regionname','regionid'); How can i print the 'regionid' inside the foreach

Comment: "Array to string conversion" on what line?  It looks like either your $CountryID is an array or your $value is an array.